# MassTransit Add custom RabbitMQ client properties

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

When using MassTransit, is it possible to add your own / custom Client properties which are available on Connections in RabbitMQ?

The only thing I managed is a custom provided connection name, which does appear in the connections overview:

[image]

With this:

```cs
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
{
    cfg.Host(RabbitMQHost, RabbitMQPort, "/", "MyCustomConnectioName", h =>
    {
        h.Username(RabbitMQUser);
        h.Password(RabbitMQPass);
    });
});
```

What I would like is some extra metadata over here:

[image: Client Properties]

Did found the line where most of this info is set, but I don't know how to interact with that, if possible.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/6f6d8f479233a084af1048204558bf459d249738/src/Transports/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport/RabbitMqTransport/RabbitMqAddressExtensions.cs#L84

Also saw this one, but that is for the Consumer:

[Add metadata when configuring an endpoint to be delivered in the Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65148041/add-metadata-when-configuring-an-endpoint-to-be-delivered-in-the-consumer)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that *can* be set is the connection name, I don't believe there is any affordance to allow other properties to be set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris. Technically it would be possible, because it's doing that will all the 9 custom properties, but it's currently not possible with MassTransit. Clear.